# jQuery UI dialog form pass variables on submit

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have jQuery UI's demo form like below. How do i submit data via ajax to a page called add.html.php?

style

```
<style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>
```

script

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var name = $( "#name" ),
        email = $( "#email" ),
        password = $( "#password" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );


    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                if ( bValid ) {

                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" );
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<h1>Existing Users:</h1>
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>johndoe1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
   <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
</div><!-- End demo -->
 <div class="demo-description">
      <p>Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process.  Embed form markup in the content area, set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `form`, add an input type of submit:

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
```

Alternatively, you can also just create a function that submits the form:

```
function fncSubmit() {
    $('form').trigger('submit');
}
```

Add this in the `ready` block:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add.html.php',
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
          //code
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
          //code
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to give the form an ID and give it a way to submit. (a button in this example)

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
  //Inputs
  <button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, you'll want to throw a click event on on the button to submit the form to the ajax call.

```
$('button#submitButton').click(
function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"add.html.php",
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
        success: function(message)
        {
          //code to execute if the ajax doesn't throw an error
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
          //code to execute if the ajax does throw an error 
        }
    });
});
```